# The ring of integers in a number field is a maximal order.

Tags: commutative-algebra, algebraic-number-theory

Let $F$ be a number field and $O_F$ be the ring of integers i.e. the integral closure of $\Bbb Z$ in $F$. I know that it is an order in $F$, i.e. a subring which is finitely generated as $\Bbb Z$-module and contains a $\Bbb Q$-basis of $F$.

I want to show that $O_F$ is a *maximal* order i.e. $R \subset F$ order $\implies R \subset O_F$.

Since $R$ is an order, it is a $\Bbb Z$-module generated by some $b_1, ..., b_n$. Then how do I show that the characteristic polynomials of the $b_i$ lie in $\Bbb Z[T]$ ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The multiplication by $b_k$ is represented in the $b_j$ generating set by an integer matrix $B_k\in M_n(\Bbb{Z})$, it is obvious that $f_k(x)=\det(xI-B_k)\in \Bbb{Z}[x]_{monic}$. Caley Hamilton gives that $f_k(B_k)=0$ in $M_n(\Bbb{Z})$ thus $f_k(b_k)=0$ in the order.

Comment: But the $b_j$ are just generating $R$ as $\Bbb Z$-module, they might not be a basis over $\Bbb Z$.

Comment: $b_k b_j = \sum_i (B_k)_{ij} b_i$. If you prefer then $a\to b_k a$ lifts to an endomorphism of $\Bbb{Z}^n$, no need that $\Bbb{Z}^n\to R$ is an isomorphism. By the way $f_k$ is the characteristic polynomial of $B_k$, there might be many possible $f_k$ for some $b_k$.

Comment: OK, this is COROLLARY 2.30 in Milne's notes on Algebraic number theory

Comment: (But the proof of Milne - see 2.4 - is much more involved than yours ; alternatively one could take a $\Bbb Z$-basis to begin with, using the non-trivial fact that a torsion-free finitely generated abelian group is actually free).

Comment: My approach is better because it works for sub $O_K$ modules of $O_L$ which are not always free (your non-trivial fact uses that $\Bbb{Z}$ is a PID)